# Save plots generated within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, flextable

I am looking for a way to save `ggplot`s and `flextables` to the workspace and later combine these objects that were generated within a loop.

Here is a simple example:

```
for (i in 1:3) {x<-rnorm(20, 5, 5-i); hist(x)}
```

In this example, x is overwritten every time and a new histogram is generated. I would want to store each histogram that is generated within the loop in the current workspace and later combine those histograms in one plot (without having to actually save each one of them). How can I go about that best?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is a bit confusing because it starts out asking about ggplot methods and then offers base graphics code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could set the `par` and get the plots into a single page

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
for (i in 1:3) {
    x<-rnorm(20, 5, 5-i)
     hist(x)
  }
```

If we want to store the plots and print, then create a `NULL` list to store the objects, and then do the plotting later

```
p1 <- vector('list', 3)
for(i in seq_along(p1)) {
    x<- rnorm(20, 5, 5-i)
    p1[[i]] <- hist(x)
}
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))
for(p in p1) plot(p)
```

Comment: Technically that does not store plots but rather vectors that `hist` Is able to turn into plots. I think the distinction is important for beginners to understand because base plotting is so different than ggplot (or lattice) results which actual do store plot objects.

Comment: @akrun: Thank you! I think the `NULL` list solution does the trick. It offers the possbility to merge the plots created within the loop afterwards individually. Can I just ask why the first for loop runs with `seq_along` while the second simply uses `p1`

Comment: @IRTFM: Ideally, I would apply the solution to `base` plots as well as to plots generated using the `ggplot` package.

Comment: @R-ista The first one is by indexing, so that it can store the output in the `list` by indexing.  where as in the second, we just need to `plot` the object.  In `R`, the for loops are all for each loop and not the traditional `for` loops in other languages i.e. `for(int i=0; i<3;i++){`

Comment: @R-ista: After searching on `[r] ggplot list of plots` you could write up a better question with an example of what you mean.

Comment: @IRTFM: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for the next question :)